# Why does java.time.Period have no constructor?

Tags: java, time, api-design, period

Instead, Period.of(int, int, int) must be used, or another static method in the same vein.

What's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Are you asking in general why static creator methods are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason - it is util class and most of util classes should be used in static manner (at least java architects wish so). You can compare it with using java.lang.Math.

The second reason, I suggest - it is reflection and serialization. I think dealing with Period.class is more convinient, but it's only suggestion. Inside implementation they have static method create() and always use create() instead of constructor.

You can also look at source code. For example, here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/e63cf6b55a95/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/Period.java

```
public static final Period ZERO = new Period(0, 0, 0);

public static Period of(int years, int months, int days) {
    return create(years, months, days);
}
private static Period create(int years, int months, int days) {
    if ((years | months | days) == 0) {
        return ZERO;
    }
    return new Period(years, months, days);
}
private Period(int years, int months, int days) {
    this.years = years;
    this.months = months;
    this.days = days;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Period is final class so can not be extended, so everyone can that Period is unmutable. Private contructor is another way to ensure that Period will be created correctly.

Comment: java.lang.String - is also final, but the constructor is public ;)